# How to calculate weeks difference and add missing Weeks with count in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am having a data frame like this I have to get missing Weeks value and count between them

```
year    Data    Id
20180406    57170   A
20180413    55150   A
20180420    51109   A
20180427    57170   A
20180504    55150   A
20180525    51109   A
```

The output should be like this.

```
Id Start year end-year count 
A  20180420      20180420      1
A  20180518      20180525      2
```

Comment: I get a bit different output, can you check it?

Comment: Your answer is correct. can we get Quarterly I have another question in the same question for quertrly

Comment: year    Data    Id
        2019Q4   57170   A
        2019Q3   55150   A
        2019Q2   51109   A 
        2019Q1   51109   A
        2018Q1   57170   B
        2018Q4   55150   B
        2017Q4   51109   C
        2017Q2   51109   C
        2017Q1   51109   C 

 Id Start year end-year count 
  

      B  2018Q2    2018Q3        2
      B  2017Q3    2018Q3        1
      

How can I achieve this using python panda

Comment: Please ask new question :)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
#converting to week period starts in Thursday
df['year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year'], format='%Y%m%d').dt.to_period('W-Thu')
#resample by start of months with asfreq
df1 = (df.set_index('year')
         .groupby('Id')['Id']
         .resample('W-Thu')
         .asfreq()
         .rename('val')
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
  Id                  year  val
0  A 2018-04-06/2018-04-12    A
1  A 2018-04-13/2018-04-19    A
2  A 2018-04-20/2018-04-26    A
3  A 2018-04-27/2018-05-03    A
4  A 2018-05-04/2018-05-10    A
5  A 2018-05-11/2018-05-17  NaN
6  A 2018-05-18/2018-05-24  NaN
7  A 2018-05-25/2018-05-31    A

#onverting to datetimes with starts dates
#http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#converting-between-representations
df1['year'] = df1['year'].dt.to_timestamp('D', how='s')
print (df1)
  Id       year  val
0  A 2018-04-06    A
1  A 2018-04-13    A
2  A 2018-04-20    A
3  A 2018-04-27    A
4  A 2018-05-04    A
5  A 2018-05-11  NaN
6  A 2018-05-18  NaN
7  A 2018-05-25    A
```

---

```
m = df1['val'].notnull().rename('g')
#create index by cumulative sum for unique groups for consecutive NaNs
df1.index = m.cumsum()

#filter only NaNs row and aggregate first, last and count.
df2 = (df1[~m.values].groupby(['Id', 'g'])['year']
                     .agg(['first','last','size'])
                     .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
                     .reset_index())

print (df2)
  Id      first       last  size
0  A 2018-05-11 2018-05-18     2
```

Comment: i have posted the question can please help  me.. How to reduce time complexity or improve the efficiency of the program finding gaps of month using python pandas